# moving new message to specific imap folder using mailkit

Tags: c#, imap, mailkit

I have simply question. Is it possible to send new message directly to specific IMAP folder using mailkit?
I previously used S22.Imap which work flawlessy but this library have strange issue with message body, it adds random carriage return sign to plain body text.
In s22.imap this function is

```
client.StoreMessage(MyMailMessage, False, box)
```

Where client is IMAP client, MyMailMessage is net.Mail.MailMesssage and box is IMAP folder.

I don't want to send message to server and again recieve it te get unique uuid and finally move it to specific folder. Maybe is better way to do this. 
Thank you in advance for help.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, literally *everything* is possible to do with MailKit :)

```
client.Inbox.Append (message);
```

That will append the message to the Inbox.

Same API exists for any other folder as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this works. But I have additional question. I want to create new folder named "stuff" .When I Use method  client.Inbox.Create("stuff", True) new folder is created but its name is "INBOX/stuff". How to create new folder with name "stuff"? Best regards. I am using Gmail.

Comment: var personal = client.GetFolder (client.PersonalNamespaces[0]); personal.Create ("stuff", true);